# Correct Firestore bandwidth/network/Internet-Egress billing factor

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am unsure how to calculate Firestore network fees. I could not find an example of this. I store a profile document in the "Firestore Database" and an image in "Cloud Storage". Let's assume the image is 900KB and the document 100KB (in total 1MB).

The Firestore Database is located in eur3 (euorpe-west3). Users have already requested 10GiB data. 1000 users from Germany (europe-west) send the request to retrieve the profile document and the image.

1. Is "Network (Egress) from Frankfurt (europe-west3) to Network (Egress) Worldwide Destinations (excluding China...) **the right pricing-factor** (currently 0,12$ based on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#internet-egress) )?
2. Are there additional bandwidth/network costs I am missing?
3. Is it correct, that Firestore will bill 0.12$?
   1000 requests * 1MB file in trasit size * 0.12$ Network (egress fee) = 0.12$

[image]

Comment: Sounds correct. I suggest you to examine estimated charges for current period to confirm numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No, as far as I can tell with the information you already provided.
3. It would be free, according to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing#internet-egress) the first 10 GB are free. However, you would be charged 0.12$ per GB from the eleventh GB onwards.